# Python Object Detecting code, unexpected error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I followed a tutorial to simulate an object detection program in python for a schoolproject. I did the exact same steps and installed the things needed. But whenever I run my code, I am getting an error:
classFile = ‘coco.names’
^

```
      line 31, in <module>
    cv2.putText(img, classNames[classId - 1].upper(), (box[0] + 10, box[1] + 30),
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could someone help me with finding out where it goes wrong?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXDD7-EnGBY&t=1515s
This is the link of the tutorial I followed.

Here is the Python code of the program I wrote by using the tutorial.

```
import cv2

thres = 0.45  # Threshold to detect object

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)
cap.set(10, 70)

classNames = []
classFile = ‘coco.names’
with open(classFile,’rt’) as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip(‘n’).split(‘n’)

    configPath = ‘ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt’
    weightsPath = ‘frozen_inference_graph.pb’

    net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
    net.setInputSize(320, 320)
    net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
    net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
    net.setInputSwapRB(True)

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=thres)
        print(classIds, bbox)

        if len(classIds) != 0:
            for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
                cv2.rectangle(img, box, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
                cv2.putText(img, classNames &  # 91;classId-1].upper(),(box&#91;0]+10,box&#91;1]+30),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                

                cv2.imshow(“Output”, img)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
```

The code should be able to recognize objects by using the webcam. I am not sure why I am getting this error, while others do not get it.

Comment: It says the error occurs in line 11, while I have that file in my library just like in the video.

Comment: `‘` is an invalid character that looks like a `'` but actually isn't. What editor are you using?

Comment: I am using PyCharm

Comment: How are you getting that character? Simply typing or copy/pasting from somewhere?

Comment: Thank you, that was the case for this error.

Comment: However, now I am getting another error

Comment: [ WARN:0] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c2l3r8zm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KFa/PycharmProjects/ObjectDtector/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=thres)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c2l3r8zm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Comment: I was typing it like it is mentioned in the tutorial video

Comment: Ok, the only error I am getting right now is:    (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'      the other ones I got fixed